# Need some help how to enter a number and count it using array

Tags: arrays, c

I have to code in an array that can count an element. For example, if the user enters a 2, 2, 2, 1,1 then the user wants to count the number 2 then the result will be ELEMENT is 2 and FREQUENCY is 3. but I have a problem with the parts of " ENTER THE NUMBER YOU WANT TO BE COUNTED". I use scanf but when I run it I cannot enter any number.

Here's my code:

```
    void frequency()
{
    system("cls");
    int num;
    int count=0;
    printf("Enter a number you want to be count: \n  ");
    scanf("i%", &num);
    
    printf(" ELEMENT  |  FREQUENCY \n ");
    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
            if (a[i]==a[num])
            count++;

    }
        printf(" \n %i ", num);
        printf(" \t\t");
        printf("%i \n ", count);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: you need `scanf("%d",&num);' also in your if statement you compare a[i] with a[num] which means number on index of num, not actual number user wants.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your problem and desribe the problem. Also please double check whether the shown code has a typo `"i%"` instead of `"%i"` (and the code you are using does not have that), or whether that is the problem.

Comment: Your array `a[]` is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your program requires understanding on two parts:

1. [Get input and split input by delimiter, which can be done by using `strtok`](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/string-split#:%7E:text=Split%20a%20string%20into%20tokens%20%2D%20strtok&text=char%20str%5B%5D%20%3D%20%22strtok%20needs,space%20will%20be%20our%20delimiter.).
2. [Algorithm for finding the duplicated elements in an array](https://www.studytonight.com/c-programs/c-program-to-find-the-frequency-of-each-element-in-the-array).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    frequency();
    return 0;
}

void frequency() {
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a number you want to be count: \n  ");
    gets(str);
    
    int init_size = strlen(str);
    char delim[] = " ";
    char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);
    char *pch;
    int arr[20];
    
    int count = 0;
    int ncount, i, j;
    int a[count], Freq[count];
    
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        /*printf("'%s'\n", ptr);*/
        /*Converts the string argument str to an integer (type int)*/
        arr[count] = atoi(ptr);

        /*strtok accepts two strings - the first one is the string to split, the second one is a string containing all delimiters*/
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        /*Initialize frequency value to -1*/
        Freq[count] = -1;
        count += 1;
    }
    
    /*Count the frequency of each element*/
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ncount = 1;
        for(j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
            /*Part to perform checking for duplicate elements*/
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                ncount++;
                /*Make sure not to count frequency of same element again*/
                Freq[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        /*If frequency of current element is not counted*/
        if(Freq[i] != 0) { 
            Freq[i] = ncount;
        }
    }

    printf("  ELEMENT  |  FREQUENCY  \n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(Freq[i] != 0) {
            printf("\t%d\t\t\t%d\n", arr[i], Freq[i]);
        }       
    }   

}
```

[image]

---

Also, from your code:

1. You did not define `i` and `n`, which is required by your `for` loop. Also, since your `for` loop is `for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)`, you have to define the value of `n`, which is the length of elements inputted by the user, in order to loop through the number of elements you expected.

```
    int i, n, num;
    ...
    ...
    for (i = 0; i<=num; i++)
```

2. Your `scanf("i%", &num);` should be `scanf("%i", &num);` instead.
3. You did not initialize your array `a`. You should have this line of code before assigning values to your array `a`. The value `20` can be adjusted by yourself depending on how many inputs are expected. Also, it can be coded in a flexible way instead of hardcoded as `20`.

```
    ...
    int i, num;
    int count=0;
    int a[20];
    ...
    ...
```

4. Lastly, it is a good practice to include the function's library before using it. In your case, you should include `#include <conio.h>` to use the `getch()` function.

Comment: Please do not advise to use `void main()`. C standard says that `main` shall be defined as an `int` function - I have just done the edit...

Comment: Just realize such thing exists. It's a new stuff for me too. Thanks @SergeBallesta.